# How to generate the missing "optional" dSYM files

Tags: xcode, dsym

I read some threads here in StackOverflow but I can't find any answer as to how I can generate these missing "optional" dSYMs. We received some crashes but they're under the missing "optional" dSYMs and we can't access those crashes without uploading these missing dSYMs.

Our app use a library that require as to disable the *bitcode* build option otherwise the app won't build due to an error.

Before when we still don't use the said library we have the *bitcode* enabled and we download the dSYMs from AppStore connect which works great without any missing "optional" dSYMs. Now we have the library and *bitcode* disable we get the dSYMs in the generated xcarchive and upload all the dSYMs to the Firebase but when we check the dSYMs tab we found some UUID listed as "optional" and are missing.

I checked all the dSYMs that are in the xcarchive but we can't find any that match with UUID of missing "optional" dSYM. Also we download some dSYM AppStore connect from our old builds and it contains 30 dSYMs but currently our xcarchives will only contains 18 dSYMs. So some dSYMs are missing when *bitcode* is disabled.

My questions:

- Where these "optional" dSYMs came from?
- Why these "optional" dSYMs are not in the xcarchive?
- Is there a way to get or generate them?